# Replicate schema change with Transactional Replication without snapshot

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have some transactional tables that are replicated with Transactional replication. But, the publication doesn't have snapshot. As of now, the replication is torn down before many any schema changes manually. To avoid tearing down of replication, I enabled schema changes on the publisher. But, schema changes happen only if the snapshot is created first. **I was wondering if there are any properties or work around that can replicate schema change on the publication without snapshot?**

Answer (score 0):

sync_type = 'NONE' on  sp_addsubscription worked